# Remove arrow input type='date'

Tags: html, css, input

I want to remove the right arrow from input type date. I want to let is work on mobile too.

Here is exactly want I want to remove:

[image]

What i've tried

```
<input type="date" class="unstyled" />

.unstyled::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
.unstyled::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

On desktop it doesen't appear..but on android devices appears.

Comment: @Alexis updated

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer..it work's on web...but on android device it appears :(

Answer (score 13):

Solution for both android and web:

```
.unstyled {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.unstyled::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
.unstyled::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: Finally a code worked for Android Chrome! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```css
 .DatePickerInput::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
 .DatePickerInput::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
     opacity:0;   
    -webkit-appearance: none;
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain your code and how this answers the question?

Comment: http://files.simformsolutions.com.s3.amazonaws.com/simformscreen/Microsoft_Teams_Notification_2019-09-10_18-38-54.png - with arrow 

http://files.simformsolutions.com.s3.amazonaws.com/simformscreen/Microsoft_Teams_Notification_2019-09-10_18-40-22.png - css added

Comment: Excellent! It gives the ability to replace the icon and retain the onclick functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
input[type="date"], 
input[type="time"], 
input[type="datetime-local"], 
input[type="month"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Placing the rules in the pseudo-elements didn't seem to work, but simply using them in the element itself does:

```
input[type="date"], input[type="time"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```