# Change the date input triangle to an SVG imported Icon

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

When you press the dropdown arrow in a date input field, a calendar appears which can be used to select a date. I would like this arrow to be replaced with an icon.

I having created a date field and would like the downwards arrow used to select a date from a calendar to be changed to an SVG icon that has been imported.

Can I change the arrow to the svg icon, or do I need to hide the arrow and create functionality so that onClick, the icon produces the calendar?

So far I have a container with the date input and an icon next to each other:

```
<InputContainer>
    <input type="date" max= "9999-12-31" />
    <CalendarIcon/>
</InputContainer>
```

Comment: I seriously doubt you can do it. May be some browsers will allow you that but forget about cross browser compatibility. The only way is to reimplement date input from scratch. Or use [existed library](https://www.cssscript.com/tag/date-picker/)

Answer (score 1):

You can go for hiding the arrow first, then using the imported image instead as the next step. For the first step, check out the answer on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41257977/1325369

Also for styling your image you can use

```
position: absolute
```

and then modify the location of your image within your container.