# Is there a way to change the position of Hover on Asp: textbox TextMode="Date"?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

i want t know if there is a way to move the position of the "DropDown, up and Down Buttons that show on hover or focus" in the asp: textbox to be on the left of the text while maintaining order.

[image: TextType Date]

i tried selecting all the children and aligning them left but it had no affect

Edit : 
here is the Html For the textbox

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="txtRecievingDate" runat="server"  placeholder="Date" TextMode="Date" meta:resourcekey="txtDateResource"></asp:TextBox>
```

Edit : 
tried the following Code With no affects :(

```css
input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button 
{
/*-webkit-align-content:center;*/
-webkit-appearance: none ;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 10px;
/*float:right;*/
/*-webkit-appearance: none;*/
}
input[type=date]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator 
{
text-align:left !important;
direction:ltr;
/*-webkit-align-content:center;*/
/*float:right;*/
}
```

So far all the positioning i tried had no affect

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with ASP. When used with a TextMode="Date" the textbox control results in a simple html5 input with type="date". This input is then [rendered differently depending on the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date), and the arrows you mention are only visible in Chrome and Opera. You might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954966/how-to-get-rid-of-x-and-up-down-arrow-elements-of-a-input-date) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41257777/remove-arrow-input-type-date/41257977)